# Where can we report misleading claims to authorities?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes skeptics come across statements that are not merely mistaken or misguided, but are dangerous or criminal. Most countries have limits to how far they take extend the concept *caveat emptor*: regulators are put in place to somewhat protect consumers from the misleading claims of advertisers.

Many skeptics, me included, find it particularly unacceptable when people make false health claims. It is one thing to waste a few dollars, and another to put lives at risk.

For each country, what are the appropriate authorities that we should report inappropriate claims?

Comment: Could you perhaps give some examples? For instance I find it unacceptable that homeopathic treatments can be advertised as beneficial, yet it is legal to do so in many countries.

Comment: @Sonny, that is a tricky one. Each authority has its own standards, priorities and budget limitations. Also, the established woo-woo merchants have worked out what weasel words to use to suggest efficacy without actually claiming it. In Australia, for instance, claiming to cure cancer is a no-no, so homeopaths generally steer clear of that, but most other sufferers aren't protected to the same level. I have included a short description of the general area, and the link generally goes to  the page that describes what sort of complaints are accepted.

Answer (score 8):

## Overall

### Police

If in doubt, especially in an emergency, consider calling the Police.

### FishBarrel

[FishBarrel](http://adventuresinnonsense.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/fishbarrel-easy-way-to-report.html) is a plugin for Google's Chrome browser that allows easy reporting of web-based claims to a growing list of authorities in a growing list of countries:

- Australia
- Canada
- Denmark
- Ireland
- New Zealand
- UK
- USA

Authorities that FishBarrel supports are marked with **[FB]** below.

## By Country

### Australia

- **[Therapeutic Goods Administration, Complaints Resolution Panel](http://www.tgacrp.com.au/)** (TGA CRP), Adverts about therapeutic goods. **[FB]**
- **[Australian Competition and Consumer Commission](http://www.accc.gov.au/content/index.phtml/itemId/54217)**, scams, business practices, misleading advertising, product safety **[FB]**

### Canada

- **[Advertising Standards Canada](http://www.adstandards.com/en/ConsumerComplaints/theConsumerComplaintsProcess.aspx)**, misleading advertising
- **[Competition Bureau Canada](http://www.competitionbureau.gc.ca/eic/site/cb-bc.nsf/eng/h_00019.html)**, packaging and labelling **[FB]**

### United Kingdom

- **[Advertising Standards Authority](http://www.asa.org.uk/)**, misleading advertising
- **[Press Complaints Commission](http://www.pcc.org.uk/complaints/makingacomplaint.html)**, accuracy in newspaper and magazines (and their websites)

### United States

None yet.

### Sweden

- **[Konsumentombudsmannen](http://www.konsumentverket.se/otherlanguages/English/This-is-how-you-file-a-complaint/)**, Misleading advertisement (in Sweden you can only make quantitative claims that you can prove), unfair contract terms, incorrect price information, dangerous products and services.

### Italy

- Send a report to the official agency: [**AGCM (Autorità Garante Concorrenza e Mercato)**](http://www.agcm.it/invia-segnalazione-online.html#wrapper)
- Avoid using other sites. The above is the official place where all reports must go.

[This is a Community Wiki: you are invited to add your own entries to it.]